# Vertex AI installation

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform, vertex-ai-search

my python won't recognize vertexai. I followed this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest

BUT my pc doesn't recognize aiplatforms when running from google.cloud import aiplatform.

I tried reinstalling and upgrading, but it keeps saying "Cannot find reference 'aiplatform' in 'imported module google.cloud'".

ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED

Installing the packages following vertexai documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the documentation you linked [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest) then first make sure you've activated your virtual environment as described in that doc.

aiplatform hast to be pip-installed.
You should be able to install ai platform with the following ([source](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/start/quickstarts/quickstart-multimodal)):
`pip install "google-cloud-aiplatform>=1.38"` or if you want to just get the latest `pip install "google-cloud-aiplatform"`

[Edit] This is how to include ImageGenerationModel:
`from vertexai.preview.vision_models import ImageGenerationModel`

[Edit] You'll have to authenticate before using
You could login via `!gcloud auth login` or
if you're running this in jupyter or google-colab-notebook use

```
    from google.colab import auth
    auth.authenticate_user()
```

Can you share the error you're getting?

Comment: THis worked haha. But I'm trying to run "from vertexai.vision_models import ImageGenerationModel"  and it says ImageGenerationModel not found. Error is: Cannot find reference 'ImageGenerationModel' in '__init__.py'

Comment: This area is clearly still in development.  Can you try importing it this way ```from vertexai.preview.vision_models import ImageGenerationModel```

Comment: THanks! It worked but now this can of worms came out.

Comment: raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_CLOUD_SDK_MISSING_CREDENTIALS)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc for more information.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\vertexai\_model_garden\_model_garden_models.py", line 291, in from_pretrained

Comment: return _from_pretrained(interface_class=cls, model_name=model_name)
  File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\vertexai\_model_garden\_model_garden_models.py", line 208, in _from_pretrained
    model_info = _get_model_info(
  File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\vertexai\_model_garden\_model_garden_models.py", line 124, in _get_model_info
    _publisher_models._PublisherModel(  # pylint: disable=protected-access

Comment: File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\aiplatform\_publisher_models.py", line 63, in __init__
    super().__init__(project=project, location=location, credentials=credentials)
  File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\aiplatform\base.py", line 556, in __init__
    self.project = project or initializer.global_config.project
  File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\aiplatform\initializer.py", line 305, in project

Comment: raise GoogleAuthError(project_not_found_exception_str) from exc
google.auth.exceptions.GoogleAuthError: Unable to find your project. Please provide a project ID by:
- Passing a constructor argument
- Using vertexai.init()
- Setting project using 'gcloud config set project my-project'
- Setting a GCP environment variable
- To create a Google Cloud project, please follow guidance at https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-project

Comment: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\dummy.py", line 40, in <module>
    model = ImageGenerationModel.from_pretrained("imagegeneration@005")
  File "C:\Users\...\venv\lib\site-packages\vertexai\_model_garden\_model_garden_models.py", line 293, in from_pretrained
    raise auth_exceptions.GoogleAuthError(credential_exception_str) from e
google.auth.exceptions.GoogleAuthError: 
Unable to authenticate your request.

Comment: Depending on your runtime environment, you can complete authentication by:
- if in local JupyterLab instance: `!gcloud auth login` 
- if in Colab:
    -`from google.colab import auth`
    -`auth.authenticate_user()`
- if in service account or other: please follow guidance in https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication

Comment: You don't have authentication setup, so you may not make calls to the api.  So you need to authenticate.

At the end of your error it suggests that you to login via ```!gcloud auth login``` or ... if you're running this in jupyter or google-colab-notebook use ```from google.colab import auth ```   and on the next line ```auth.authenticate_user()```

A clear example of a notebook setting up authentication and making API calls can be found here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/generative-ai/blob/main/vision/getting-started/image_generation.ipynb